# Css flex item that occupy multiple rows and/or columns

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to define a 4-column grid layout using CSS flex where the default flex child is a quarter of the parent width and an equal division of the parent height, and then I'd like to define two classes (`.dw` and `.dh`), which doubles the child's width and/or height, when applied. In case is helps, for my setup, a child will only be one of the following class combinations: `.child`, `.child.dw`, `.child.dw.dh`. It will never have the `.dh` class without also having the `.dw` property, but it can have the `.dw` class without the `.dh` class.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to reliably do both at the same time. My code that doubles height is also a bit finicky.

Here's my markup:

```
<div id="parent" class="sec">
  <div class="child dh dw"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <!-- etc. -->
</div>
```

Here's the first piece of CSS I discovered that allows a `.dw`class:

```
#parent {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#parent .child {
  flex: 1 0 calc(25% - 10px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px;
}

#parent .child.dw { flex: 1 0 calc(50% - 10px); }
```

The above comes out looking like the following, which is exactly what I'm looking for in a `.dw` child.

[image]

And here's the piece of CSS I discovered in which a `.dh` class almost works.

```
#parent {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#parent .child {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  margin: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#parent .child.dh { flex-basis: 50%; }
```

But as you can see from the next screenshot, it doesn't properly set the `.dh` child's height properly, and it doesn't use up all the vertical space of the parent container.

[image]

For reference, here's what I'm trying to achieve with a child that has both `.dw` and `.dh`. Please ignore the fact that it now has two less children - I simply used paint.net to stretch the first screenshot's `.dw` child to cover the two children below it.

[image]

Comment: spanning both rows and column requires to use the grid layout, flex can only one or the other .That's one of the main difference ;)

Comment: @temaniafif , i think the duplicate you pickup do not cover the question , it is about spanning both rows and columns together, flex cannot and the duplicate doesn't either ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I was adding two duplicate, I started with the easiest one to find

Comment: @TemaniAfif okay, however the only way  i see is grid ;) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/QWjqRLz there won't be any flex duplicate without rethink the html structure ;) or a javascript aside